# Python UIPath - Unable to read arguments from UIPath and pass it to the python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, uipath

Here is an image showing Python scope activity:

[image: Image shows python scope activity]

I am trying to execute a script in UIPath using Python scope, Python load activity, invoke python method and get python object which is mentioned below:

The execution is getting completed without any errors/exceptions. But there is no .xlsx file written.
The code is not getting executed/ the arguments are not passed correctly.
Kindly help.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
def excel_data (arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4):
    df = pd.DataFrame({‘SODA RISK’: [arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]}) 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(‘try_python.xlsx’, engine=‘xlsxwriter’) 
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=‘Sheet1’) 
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code executes without any error, there will be an Excel file. You did not provide a custom path, so the file most likely gets created in the NuGet package folder (your user's name and the package versions most likely will be different):

```
C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\uipath.python.activities\1.1.6863.33404\lib\net452
```

You may want to change your code so that the full path can be provided as an argument:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

def excel_data (fullPath, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'SODA RISK': [arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]}) 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fullPath, engine='xlsxwriter') 
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1') 
    writer.save()
```

Also, since your method does not return anything you could just get rid of the `Get Python Object` activity. If there's an error (e.g. a missing package), UiPath will throw an exception.