# Return arguments to UiPath Studio sequence from Python code invoked

Tags: python, python-3.x, uipath

In UiPath studio, the Invoke Python Method has parameters under input as Input parameters, instance and name. The input parameters helps in passing arguments from the UiPath workflow to Python code.
Is there any way to access the arguments returned from Python code back to UiPath?
If yes, Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python UIPath - Unable to read arguments from UIPath and pass it to the python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812671/python-uipath-unable-to-read-arguments-from-uipath-and-pass-it-to-the-python-c)

Comment: There is a difference. Arguments are being imported from UiPath to python code in the link attached. I want to return back the values from Python code to UiPath. Is it possible? If yes, Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your Python script:

```
def say_hello(name):
    return "hello " + name
```

1. Add a `Python Scope`. Make sure to set the path to the executable.
2. Add a `Load Python Script` activity, and create a new output variable to store the result in.
3. Add an `Invoke Python Method` activity and configure it as follows: [image]
4. Add a Get Python Object activity, and convert the returned object into a .NET object (string in our case): [image]

That's it. Here's the full workflow:

[image]